# PostgreSQL query interval data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to perform a query which I can't figure out how to write. I have a `claims` table

```
claims table:
 - id
 - date_received
```

I want to grab the new claim count for each day for over 30 days. The naive solution I was trying to come up with was this.

```
select count(*) 
  from claims
  where date_received 
    BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - interval '1 month' 
        AND CURRENT_DATE
  group by date_received;
```

This works but it groups by exact timestamp and not same day. How could I make it so it groups by same day?

**EDIT**

I was able to figure it our updated query:

```
select date_received::date as date, count(id) as new_claims
  from claims 
  where date_received BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - interval '1 month'
              AND CURRENT_DATE
  group by date_received::date 
  order by date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, claims arrive in the *past*, not the future, so you would want:

```
select date_received::date, count(*)
from claims
where date_received >= CURRENT_DATE - interval '1 month' and
      date_received < CURRENT_DATE
group by date_received::date
order by date_received::date;
```

Comment: How could I group by day instead of the exact date? for example `2018-07-18 15:49:33` and `2018-07-18 15:49:59` are grouped separately

Comment: @Rodrigo . . . That is rather far removed from your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Gordon's answer, you can use `date_trunc(precision, timestamp)` to get what you want:

```
select date_received::date, count(*)
from claims
where date_received >= 
      date_trunc('day', CURRENT_DATE - interval '1 month') 
  and date_received < CURRENT_DATE
group by date_received::date
order by date_received::date;
```

See [date_trunc()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) for details.